# Typescript 0.9.5 won't compile .d.ts

Tags: angularjs, typescript

When I copy my AngularJS code from an existing project into a new project, typescript compiler reports an error for the new project as below:

```
Error 2 Build: Could not find symbol 'bool'.Scripts\AngularTS\ng\route.d.ts Line 8 Column 26
```

Yes, I understand that the route.d.ts is old that still uses 'bool' which should be 'boolean'.

But the strange thing is: my existing project does not report the error. (Same computer, same typescript compiler 0.9.5).

I tried to edit route.d.ts (added random chars) in my exisiting project, still no error was reported. It seems that typescript compiler won't compile it!

So my question is why typescript behaved so differently in the two situations?

======== Updated ========

The latest finding is: when there is another error, this error will be reported.
If there is no other errors, then it won't be.
So strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bool` vs `boolean` error is actually really a warning. TypeScript will still happily compile your code. You can even 'get away with it' in later versions of the compiler, although the type won't be `boolean` it will be `any`.

So it is worth fixing as you will lose proper checking if you don't update to `boolean`.

```
var x: bool = true;

if (x === true) {
    alert("Isn't it though");
}
```

[See this on the TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=var%20x%3a%20bool%20=%20true;%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20%28x%20===%20true%29%20%7B%0D%0A%09alert%28%22Isn%27t%20it%20though%22%29;%0D%0A%7D).